# Class Inheritance: use parent's function on child's member

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes `PARENT` and `CHILD`, where the latter inherits from its parent a function that uses a private constant member value. I expected it to use the member value of the child, but instead it uses the parent's value, unless I redefine the function in the child again (see `CHILD2`).

An easy solution would be to redefine the function in each child (I expect to have maybe 10 children-types), but that doesn't seem right to me.

To make it a bit clearer, here is a minimum working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// PARENT Class that has a function to talk
class PARENT {
public:
    void talk() {
        std::cout << "Hello my name is " << name.c_str() << "\n";
    }
private:
    const std::string name = "Parent";
};


// CHILD Class, inherits from PARENT, but should use the different name
class CHILD : public PARENT {
private:
    const std::string name = "Child";
};


// CHILD2 Class, that redefines the talk-function
class CHILD2 : public PARENT {
public:
    void talk() {
        std::cout << "Hello my name is " << name.c_str() << "\n";
    }
private:
    const std::string name = "Child2";
};


int main() {
    PARENT parent;
    CHILD child;
    CHILD2 child2;

    parent.talk(); // expected 'Hello my name is Parent' // GOOD
    child.talk();  // expected 'Hello my name is Child'  // BAD, it uses 'Parent'
    child2.talk(); // expected 'Hello my name is Child2' // GOOD
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to use the `talk()`-function on the child's `name`, without re-declaring the function for each child-class?

Comment: Why does a child have its own name member?

Comment: Add explicit `PARENT` constructor accepting name value to initialize `name` field with and call it from derived classes.

Comment: you mean its better to have the name member defined in the parent and then assign the value in the constructor of each child?

Comment: `std::cout << name.c_str()` ? `std::cout << name;`

Comment: As you noted from the answer below, defining in a child class a variable with the same name of one defined in its parent class is usually a bad idea (and it's not needed in your case). The variabile in child class somehow "hide" the one in parent class, not within functions declared in parent, but not for ones declared in child. Compiler works properly, human programmers are easily confused.

Comment: Your current code doesn't contain the `child` 's `talk` method. It should definitely print out `Child` (or not use its parent string) if there were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just keep adding `std::string` members. That's wasteful to begin with, and is the cause of you looking for a workaround. Instead of default initializing all those new strings, allow a child class to provide a value for it in the parent. Add a protected constructor:

```
// PARENT Class that has a function to talk
class PARENT {
public:
    void talk() {
        std::cout << "Hello my name is " << name << "\n";
    }

    PARENT() = default; // To still allow default construction as before

protected:
    explicit PARENT(std::string const& name) : name(name) {}

private:
    const std::string name = "Parent";
};
```

And use it in each child class constructor. Now there's only *one* `talk` function, and each child is allowed a customization point.

```
class CHILD : public PARENT {
public:
    CHILD() : PARENT("Child") {}
};
```

Comment: I added a `public` to the CHILD, now it works like a charm! Will accept it ASAP!

Comment: @StoryTeller, your `PARENT`'s `name` defined as `const` can be reassigned in the constructor ?

Comment: @StackUnderblow - It's not reassigned, it's initialized there. The default initializer is only used if the constructors member initializer list doesn't provide one explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Leave a `name` variable only in the parent, pass it to the PARENT's constructor, init it to the name you want in the child and do not override `talk`

Comment: Code example is always better than a description of said code.

Comment: That's debatable. If you tried to do something, based off of a suggestion you have no way of knowing if you did it correctly, short of asking again, which defeats the purpose of such answer. Comment section is better suited for general suggestions. Answer section is meant for answers.

Comment: Actually I wanted to put a sample but StoryTeller was faster so I gave up. Maybe I  should delete my answer anyway